# Difficulties with Data Model Design

Tags: powerbi, datamodel, star-schema

Good morning,

I am new to power BI and I'm designing a dashboard that's supposed to be simple.

I have a table that contains planned budgets for 2024 and 2025 for a selection of partners per sector.

[image]

On the other hand, I have another table where I track the funding received per appealing agency, per sector and sub-sector and donor.
[image]

The objective is to design a funding tracker that allows for showing the rate of funding and compare it by sector, by partner, for each year.

My thinking is to use the funding table as a FacTable and then, the dimensions are: appealing agency, sector (& subsector), and year, however I'm receiving many errors statitng that the relationships are many-to-many. I have tried a workaround, it does seem to work as I'm able to filter all by date, sector and agency but I'm sure there is a better approach than this.

[image]

any guidance on how I can establish a Star Schema model for this dashboard?

I appreciate any support you can provide me.

Cheers

Comment: Looks like you've achieved a Star Model. What is the issue/ask? Where were you getting many-to-many relationships? And how did you resolve?

Comment: I'm failing to see how this could be a star models I have the impression that I have two fact tables (Funding  and Budget) that I'm linking with common dimensions (Year, Sector, Agency).

I have tried to define the budget table as a dimension table but that didn't work out and I had difficulties linking it to any elements in the FactFunding table. I had to consider it as a Fact table on its own for it to work.

I am only looking for a feedback to the approach that I considered. I imagine there are other efficient ways of doing it.

Comment: Yes, you have a Star Model with two fact tables, nothing wrong with that. What you have above is good. It could be better with using IDs for the relationships, making Donor a Dimenson, moving Sub-sector to DimSector, have a proper Date table with Year dates being first of the year, and month dates being the start of the month.